# Dynamic template path in MapServer

Tags: php, dictionary, mapserver

I'm building a PHP web-mapping application which has own mapserver.
I have two templates for each layer - a template for guest and for logged user.
My normal mapfile has a line like

```
TEMPLATE "templates/template.html"
```

But I have also a templates_guest folder which contains html templates for guests.
How to change the 'TEMPLATE' parameter in runtime?
If user is logged in, the TEMPLATE path should be templates_guest/template.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you could accomplish this via the query string.

I would recommend doing this via the url query string. Edit the template path in the query string like this:

```
...&map.web.template='templates_guest/template.html'...
```

For more info look here in the [MapServer Docs](http://mapserver.org/cgi/controls.html#cgi-mapfile-change-parameters)